# Проблема с питоном и PostgreSQL

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

Как решить проблему?
[image: Говнокод]
Есть такой код, нужно как-то автоматизировать чтобы он создал сам таблицу

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-10' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=UndefinedTable('ОШИБКА:  отношение "users" не существует\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (800113578)\n                      ^\n')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
   for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
   return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 101, in notify
   await self.dispatcher.middleware.trigger(f"pre_process_{self.middleware_key}", args + (data,))
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares.py", line 53, in trigger
   await app.trigger(action, args)
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares.py", line 106, in trigger
   await handler(*args)
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\!!bot\middlewares.py", line 14, in on_pre_process_update
   user = sql_orm.select_user(id)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\!!bot\sql_orm.py", line 13, in select_user
   sql.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (%s)', [id])
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: ОШИБКА:  отношение "users" не существует
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (800113578)
                     ^
```

Comment: Нужен - напишите, возникнут проблемы - задавайте вопросы :)

Comment: Первое - замените скрин на текст. Второе - вы же понимаете, что таблица в БД это не переменная в коде? И если ваш проект во время работы не нашел нужной для него таблицы, то это, мягко говоря, не правильно(BUG). Вы либо с проектом скрипты до БД не докатили, либо ошибка в имени таблицы(а может все сразу). **Вариант:** при старте проверять наличие необходимых таблиц в БД и если их там нет, создавать, заранее подготовленным скриптом. В `sql` нет конструкции вида **SELECT OR CREATE TABLE**

Comment: @SwaD зато есть ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков А как это запихнуть в **select**? Приходит в БД селект к несуществующей таблице, как по селекту создать таблицу и повторить селект(там правда ничего не будет)... CREATE IF NOT EXIST это для скриптов создания таблиц, а не для скриптов выборки данных.

Comment: @SwaD Таки я предлогаю перед селектом выполнить создание таблицы, а вот структуру автору придется искать самостоятельно :)

Comment: @SwaD ну или если совсем жестить - написать плагин для посгри xD

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Надо просто при старте проверять таблицы(можно сразу скриптом создания), если косяков по коду и БД много(а тут как я понимаю много, раз такой вопрос), то я еще бы и структуру проверял, что в таблицах есть нужные поля, а уже после этого продолжил стартовать приклад.